# "ping" fails when running from google- cloud on specific IP

Tags: networking, bash, google-cloud-platform, ip, ping

I'm trying to access [www.fastlane.co.il](https://www.fastlane.co.il) trough google cloud servers.
I got the IP 81.218.67.65. When i ping it locally on my computer it works fine.

Local results:

```
Pinging www.fastlane.co.il [81.218.67.65] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 81.218.67.65: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=118
Reply from 81.218.67.65: bytes=32 time=8ms TTL=118
Reply from 81.218.67.65: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=118
Reply from 81.218.67.65: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=118
```

but when i do it from the server it is stuck like this:

```
PING www.fastlane.co.il (81.218.67.65) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

How can i contact this website through the cloud (i need a script to run)?

EDIT:
I think this site is only available in my country (israel). Is there any (simple) way to fool it?
I want to create a python script for it and run it on a server

Comment: If the API is using geolocation, then you will need to send the requests from a server/service that gelocation allows. The is often performed via VPNs.

Answer (score 2):

Checked from my computer and i got the same error, there is no ping result. Also i cant reach the Server on another common Port.

Can you reach the site with curl from your computer ?

```
curl www.fastlane.co.il
```

Try to check the Server for any firewall rules or IP Filters, when the connection works on your computer some policies blocking other connections.